# Chrome extension's manifest.json `host_permissions: ["<all_urls>"]` is modified to `host_permissions: ["%3Call_urls>"]`

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am creating a chrome extension to take screenshot of a specific webpage using [chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab) which requires permission [all_urls](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/match-patterns#special).

When I test the extension it works fine but when I install extension from [web store](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/pickcel-player/pllfmbcgfjgapdmnmnlalalnpmmocopc) it does not work and throw an error:

```
Error: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.
```

After debugging for a long time, I decided to check into chrome's downloaded extension and there I see `host_permissions: ["<all_urls>"]` is modified to `host_permissions: ["%3Call_urls>"]`, seems like it encoded the angle backet to url encoded string.

Comment: It's the same thing as the original `<all_urls>`, the web store replaces it for no real benefit for historical reasons (it might have been necessary to combat XSS). The problem is caused either by a bug in Chrome or the tab is not a web page and your extension lacks `activeTab` permission or you call the API not inside a user-initiated action.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes, `activeTab` is missing but it's working locally! activeTab permission is not required if it has `<all_urls>`

Comment: It's required in certain cases listed in my comment and in the documentation.